# Obtain .avi file info from command line

Tags: command-line, files, video

What is the best way to obtain information as bitrate, framerate, width/height of an movie file (in my case `.avi`) from the command line? I am looking for a basic tool that works similarly as ImageMagicks `identify`.

Running `mplayer` already gives this information (but also does a lot more):

```
VIDEO:  [FMP4]  800x711  24bpp  25.000 fps  1320.9 kbps (161.2 kbyte/s)
```

Is there a way to make `mplayer` only give this output (I did not find it in the man) or is there another standard bash-command to obtain the same information?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/249828/command-to-see-media-file-info-in-terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mplayer` comes with an `midentify` utility that does mostly what you want.

The output looks like variable assignments, so it is pretty easy to use in scripts/simple to parse.

If `midentify` isn't installed with your `mplayer` package, you might have an `midentify.sh` script in `/usr/share/mplayer` or something like that. If not, `midenfify` just runs `mplayer` with a specific set of arguments:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#
# This is a wrapper around the -identify functionality.
# It is supposed to escape the output properly, so it can be easily
# used in shellscripts by 'eval'ing the output of this script.
#
# Written by Tobias Diedrich <ranma+mplayer@tdiedrich.de>
# Licensed under GNU GPL.

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Usage: midentify.sh <file> [<file> ...]"
        exit 1
fi

mplayer -vo null -ao null -frames 0 -identify "$@" 2>/dev/null |
    sed -ne '/^ID_/ {
                      s/[]()|&;<>`'"'"'\\!$" []/\\&/g;p
                    }'
```

The `-ao`, `-vo` and `-frames` parameters prevent `mplayer` from actually playing the clip. The rest is just formatting.

Example:

```
$ midentify some_random.avi 
ID_VIDEO_ID=0
ID_AUDIO_ID=0
...
ID_VIDEO_BITRATE=258488
ID_VIDEO_WIDTH=320
ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT=240
ID_VIDEO_FPS=29.917
...
ID_LENGTH=4216.76
...
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=64000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=22050
...
```

Comment: midentify is not installed on this system, mplayer movie.avi -identify gives this kind of output, but also plays the movie.

Comment: It's just a wrapper script, I edited some information in - you could adapt that `mplayer` command to suit your exact needs.

Comment: Your script does exactly what I need. Also via ssh without X11 forwarding whatsoever. Thank you!

Comment: Edited to better reflect that it's not _my_ script, it comes with the  `mplayer` source code.

Comment: Nice thanks but it shows me video bitrate of 0 (this is MPEG4 AVC VBR). :-(

Answer (score 5):

[mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) command also gives you lots of information:

```
$ mediainfo IMGP3793.AVI 
General
Complete name                            : IMGP3793.AVI
Format                                   : AVI
Format/Info                              : Audio Video Interleave
File size                                : 121 MiB
Duration                                 : 2mn 16s
Overall bit rate                         : 7 439 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : JPEG
Codec ID                                 : MJPG
Duration                                 : 2mn 16s
Bit rate                                 : 7 339 Kbps
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Original height                          : 960 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 30.288 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Interlaced
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.789
Stream size                              : 119 MiB (99%)

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings, Endianness              : Little
Format settings, Sign                    : Unsigned
Codec ID                                 : 1
Duration                                 : 2mn 16s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 88.2 Kbps
Channel count                            : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 11.025 KHz
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Stream size                              : 1.44 MiB (1%)
Alignment                                : Aligned on interleaves
Interleave, duration                     : 33 ms (1.00 video frame)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **file** command.

Comment: Easy and fast solution, basically what I was looking for. Only bitrate information is missing here.