# Show video files with its size

Tags: shell, shell-script, terminal, osx

I need all the `.mp4` files' dimensions to be printed with the file name.
For example:

```
1_VIDEO.mp4 1204x680
```

Comment: Ok Guys, solved it

find * -name '*.mp4' -exec exiftool -directory -fileName -imageSize {$1} \;

first install http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html#OSX "ExifTool"

Comment: Could you then add this as an answer, please.

Comment: Please write that up as an answer and accept it so other's know that your issue's been resolved.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29101/obtain-avi-file-info-from-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok Guys, solved it

```
find . -name '*.mp4' -exec exiftool -directory -fileName -imageSize {} \;
```

first install [ExifTool](http://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/install.html#OSX).

Answer (score 6):

With [`exiftool`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/):

```
$ exiftool -q -p '$FileName $ImageSize' ./*.mp4
foo.mp4 640x480
test.mp4 1280x800
```

Comment: Ah exiftool. I knew there was a tool, couldn't remember the name.

Comment: For some reason exiftool returns incorrect information on some files. ffmpeg seems a lot more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ ffmpeg -i 1_VIDEO.mp4 2>&1 | \
      grep -E 'width|height|Input.*from' | \
      paste -sd' ' | \
      awk '{print $5, $8"x"$11}' | \
      sed "s/'\|://g"
```

#### Example

```
$ ffmpeg -i pizzahut_pizzahead_and_steve.flv 2>&1 | \
      grep -E 'width|height|Input.*from' | \
      paste -sd' ' | \
      awk '{print $5, $8"x"$11}' | \
      sed "s/'\|://g"
pizzahut_pizzahead_and_steve.flv 320x240
```

#### Breakdown

1. The first grep

   ```
   $ ffmpeg -i pizzahut_pizzahead_and_steve.flv 2>&1 | \
               grep -E 'width|height|Input.*from'
   Input #0, flv, from 'pizzahut_pizzahead_and_steve.flv':
       width           : 320
       height          : 240
   ```
2. paste

   This combines the 3 lines of output from the output in #1, into a single line.

   ```
   Input #0, flv, from 'pizzahut_pizzahead_and_steve.flv':     width           : 320     height          : 240
   ```
3. awk & sed

   The remaining 2 commands cleanup the output from `paste` and format it so that it looks like this:

   ```
   pizzahut_pizzahead_and_steve.flv 320x240
   ```

Answer (score -1):

does 
`ls -lA | awk {'print $5, "\t",  $9'}`

work in osx ?

Comment: No that isn't working..

Comment: That shows the files size, not the dimensions of the video.

Comment: wops, sorry!
"I need all the .mp4 files' dimensions to be printed"

didn't read the example!